# Bad Request returned only with IE 11 on remote machine for XHR that passes credentials

Tags: c#, ajax, internet-explorer

I've been trying to figure out what piece I'm missing when making an XHR to an MS Web API that requires windows auth.

This request works locally on both Chrome and IE 11 as well as Chrome on a remote box (not the server).  The problem is IE 11 on the remote box.

According to the dev tools, IE makes 3 requests.  The first two requests pass an Authorization: Negotiate header and return 401s (preflights for CORS?).  However, the third returns a 400.  It seems like it fails to authenticate in a way that I don't understand, especially since other browsers and local tests work.

The API is a self-hosted OWIN console app.  Here's the startup:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

    var listener = (HttpListener)appBuilder.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];

    if (listener != null)
    {
        listener.AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate = request =>
        {
            if (string.Compare(request.HttpMethod, "OPTIONS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                return AuthenticationSchemes.Anonymous;
            }
            else
            {
                return AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
            }
        };
    }

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Here's the client-side XHR call:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://xxxx:9000/api/test/something', true);
request.timeout = 10000;
request.withCredentials = true;
request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        console.log('done');
    } else {
        console.error('error');
    }
};

request.onerror = function() {
    // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

And the API Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("something")]
    public IHttpActionResult Something()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

2 Requests that return 401 and the one that returns a 400:

```
First 401:

   Request URL: http://xxxx:9000/xxxx
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized

Request Headers
   Accept: */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en-US
   Authorization: Negotiate [token]
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Host: xxxx:9000
   Referer: http://xxxx/xxxx.html
   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3)

Response Headers

   Content-Length: 0
   Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 14:03:09 GMT
   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate [token]

-------------
Second 401

   Request URL: http://xxxx:9000/xxxx
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 401 / Unauthorized

Request Headers

   Accept: */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en-US
   Authorization: Negotiate [token]
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Host: xxxx:9000
   Referer: http://xxxx/xxxx.html
   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3)

Response Headers

   Content-Length: 0
   Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 14:03:09 GMT
   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
   WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate [token]

-----------
400

   Request URL: http://xxxx:9000/xxxx
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 400 / Bad Request

Request Headers

   Accept: */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en-US
   Authorization: Negotiate [token]
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Host: xxxx:9000
   Referer: http://xxxx/xxxx.html
   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3)

Response Headers

   Content-Length: 0
   Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 14:03:12 GMT
   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

Comment: Can you attach that failing request and 2 before (I mean their request and response headers).

Comment: Added that info in the post.  Thanks.

Comment: Strange, I don't see any CORS preflight requests, and http 400 code is strange to return for auth errors. Are you sure there are nothing in logs (iis, you application windows logs) about this error?

Comment: Could you try to add your server address as a trusted website in ie11?

Comment: There does not appear to be anything interesting in windows application logs or applications -> internet explorer logs.

Adding the server address as a trusted website does not seem to help.  Same error as before.

Comment: Can you try moving the line `request.withCredentials = true;` to before the call to `open()`?

Comment: What's the document mode IE11 is running under on the local and on the remote machine?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I've tried using a helper lib like axios `withCredentials` and get the same issue so I don't think order is the problem in this case.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit 11.  IT policy sets IE to run Intranet sites under compatibility mode.  I'm telling IE to run my site in Edge mode via X-UA-Compatible meta tag on pages.

Answer (score 2):

**Trusted site**

My guess is that the remote machine is restricted by domain policies and your site is not seen as a trusted site on that machine.

Add (or ask to add, if policies are set by IT) your website the appropriate security zone (Local intranet or Trusted sites) and the problem should be fixed.

**Document mode**

While you're at it, also see if they're pushing any old document mode for IE11 to run in).

**Enable CORS for WebAPI**

I see you already call `UseCors` on OWIN's `IAppBuilder`, but additionally you can try to enable CORS on the `HttpConfiguration` instance:

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE"));
```

Comment: This was my original thought as well.  I added my site to the trusted sites list, but that didn't seem change the error.  Also told IE to run the site in Edge mode via X-UA-Compatible meta tag on my pages.  Same issue as before.

Comment: Are you sure the meta tag is taken into account? You should check which mode it actually uses on the remote machine.

Comment: My way of confirming was to remove the meta tag and check the IE mode in dev tools.  Without the tag it's 7, with the meta tag included it's 11.

Comment: I've added an additional hint for enabling CORS for WebAPI. After that, I'm out of tips :p

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to pass a HttpOnly cookie/token using XHR:

1. Use axios or similar library on the client and use a config containing withCredentials:

   ```
       import axios from 'axios';
       const config = {
           method: 'get',
           url: 'http://xxxx:9000/api/test/something',
           timeout: 5000,
           withCredentials: true
       };
       //if (setCookie === true) {
           //config.mode = 'no-cors'; // <= THIS IS IMPORTANT IF SETTING COOKIE!
       //}
       const response = await axios(config);
   ```
2. On the server set cors options:

   ```
   const corsOptions = {
       origin: 'http://xxxx:9000', // Set explicit origin!
       methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], // Allow method(s)!
       credentials: true //enable server to see credentials.
   };
   ```

source: [xhr.spec.whatwg.org](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)

I hope it works for you too, it took some time before it worked. If it fails then [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) long shot might work. Finally if you are using windows it is also possible it is a local problem:

> Whatever security zone your website is in (Internet Options >
>   Security) make sure you ENABLE the following setting in your zone:
>   Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains.